# Same question asked by two users answered by the same person

Tags: discussion, support

Today I saw two questions [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101605/how-to-write-a-program-to-conert-infix-to-postfix-by-using-stl-in-c) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101287/to-write-a-c-code-using-stl) which have the same content without a single word difference.

> Aishwarya wants to convert infix expression to postfix and then perform evaluation of postfix expression. We can only use vectors in stl. Can  anybody please give a code for this?

The Question has the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101605/how-to-write-a-program-to-conert-infix-to-postfix-by-using-stl-in-c) given by the same person.

Is there something wrong? What action should I take on this?

**Edit:** The person deleted answer.

Comment: Close both as unclear

Comment: What if there are all three user are same created three account and accept the answer and third user get reputation.

Comment: Looks like maybe a same homework question. I'd say they're both **too broad**.

Comment: Identical characters in identical order.  Identical misuse of the article 'a'.  It's the same text.  The probability of two posters issuing that question independently is vanishingly small.   Of course, the problem of how to handle the question is simplified by its 'gimme teh codez' attribute: downCloseVote both.

Comment: Probably cut-and-paste from a homework assignment. The two OPs are in the same class, and the respondent did the same course last year.  Not really what stack overflow is for.

Comment: I saw the same thing happen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110971/click-once-runs-x-click-again-runs-y/34111007#34111007) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108118/cycle-through-text-in-jquery/34108152#34108152) today as well...

Comment: @Josh It gets even worse when a very high rep user does that :-(

Comment: @DavidWallace If Cut-and paste form assignment question then, assignment question does not have sentence like: `Can anybody please give a code for this?` Even this sentence are also same in the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When I see multiple repeated questions by the same user, I vote/flag to close as a dup (if the first question is on topic) and will leave a comment for the OP explaining this is not good practice. If they have given a reason why it is duplicated, I address that reason and reinforce that it is still not good practice.

If I see the same pair of users (what I refer to as a tag team) posting and answering low quality questions, I flag one or both of the users and make a custom mod flag saying I suspect it's either the same person or a pair of people repeatedly posting on the site. That way the mods can see if the users are the same person, or at least they are notified and can act accordingly, particularly if the behaviour continues.

***Caveat: if the original question is off topic I flag it and any subsequent question for the reason that it is off topic, e.g. unclear, not as a dupe of an off topic question.***